# Is deciding termination easier than deciding rationality?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, irrational-numbers, decidability

Irrationality proofs are usually extremely hard. Unknown cases include the Euler-Mascheroni-constant $\gamma$ , $e+\pi$ and $e\cdot \pi$

> Is it easier to decide whether a given number has a terminating expansion in a given base ?

I think this is not easier, but is there a reference ?

Comment: Probably a more mathematically interesting property is, given an integer $n$ greater than $1,$ is the number rational with reduced denominator divisible by $n$? Of course, both this type of question and your question are only going to be easier than deciding rationality when the answer is NO. This does seem somewhat interesting, however. For example, maybe we can't (yet) determine whether $e + \pi$ is rational, but we can determine that if it were rational, then when reduced its denominator is not divisible by $7.$ This is somewhat similar to other things we are able to prove, **(continued)**

Comment: namely lower bounds on the size of the integers that can be used to provide a fractional representation of the number. For example, I'm sure it's known (a do'able computer search suffices) that if $e + \pi$ were rational and we have $\frac{p}{q} = e + \pi$ for integers $p$ and $q,$ then each of $p$ and $q$ have to be greater than $1,000,000.$

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro A large denominator does not mean a denominator that is not divisible by $7$. The denominator need not be prime !

Comment: I'm talking about two DIFFERENT ways that one might prove something about possible rational representations (maybe can't prove rational, but can disprove some types of rationals). One is to disprove divisibility by certain integers (essentially your question), and the other is to disprove lower bounds on the "size" of the rationals (for example, it is not known if $\gamma$ is rational, but it is known that [any fractional representation of $\gamma$ must be a fraction with denominator greater than ${10}^{44,663}).$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant#Properties)

Comment: Note in my first comment that when I was making the transition from divisibility to size, I wrote: "This is somewhat similar to other things we are able to prove ..."

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro The point is that we cannot say anything about the divisors of the (possible) denominator. We can just bound it. In particular, it could be a power of $10$ or any integer with prime factors only $2$ and $5$. If we could rule such things out, we would have a non-terminating proof.

Comment: In a given base (e.g. base $10$) you cannot even decide whether a non-terminating expansion represents a rational or an irrational number only by (algorithmically) inspecting all its decimal places. You will never be able to check whether a potential periodicity is there forever (showing that it would be rational).